# Signing documents with iText 7 and GlobalSign DSS in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

We are trying to create a document signing solution with iText (v7) and GlobalSign DSS.
Does anybody have experience with this? I can't find a lot (if any) examples on this. How is one supposed to combine the API requests ("identity", "certificate_path", "timestamp", "identity/.../sign",...) with iText?

I have found some sample code, but it is in Java and uses an old version of iText (with the PdfStamper).
The goal is to create LTV enabled signatures (including a visible seal), with the server certificate stored at GlobalSign's HSM.

Many thanks for any help and/or sympathy!

Comment: did you get this to work? I'm looking for the same solution. The documentation is very limited: https://downloads.globalsign.com/acton/media/2674/digital-signing-service-api-documentation

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/SimonChris/SigningServer

I have published an open-source implementation above. The license is AGPL, as required by iText7, but you can run the program on its own server and have your main application send PDF data for signing through the REST API.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the guide for both c# and Java on
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7